# Show All Local Variables in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I think I already know the answer to this question is "No", but I ask anyway just in case I missed something in the dox.

I  adore the Eclipse "Quick Outline" feature where I can easily see all the member variables and methods for the class my cursor is currently located in by typing Control + O (or Navigate -> Quick Outline).

What would be equally useful is a way to see all local variables available at the point my cursor is.  Does such a feature exist?

Thanks!

Comment: It helps to not have methods longer than a single page. ;-)

Comment: The closest thing that comes to mind is syntax highlighting. By default, local variables show up in the same color as a zillion other things, but you could change them to something distinctive like a bright orange background. Then it would be easy to see all of them, but it would be in the editor, not the outline.

Comment: Which language/editor are you working with?  It might make a difference.

Comment: @Thilo:  Good advice if you're not working on a mini, where a "page" is only about 15 lines long.  But yes shorter methods are better I agree.

Comment: @nitind: Java 6 and Eclipse Helios's standard text editor.

Comment: I was just dreaming of this feature as well.  Yes, auto complete is useful, but why isn't variable in scope in the outline view as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can probably use content assist for this. Just press Ctrl+Space on an empty line, the resulting content assist popup should offer suggestions on what can be inserted at that point,  local variables should be on top followed by fields and then member functions.