# How do I get Eclipse to recognize "inline declarations"?

Tags: java, eclipse

I put "inline declarations" in quotes in the title because part of my problem is I don't know what to call this. I'm very new to Java and to programming in general, so the phrase "inline declarations" is the closest I can come to describing what I'm talking about to Google or other search engines, and I haven't found any answers. For all I know, it isn't a "declaration" at all (though I think it is, since I looked up the difference between declaration, instantiation, and initialization).  Hopefully, I'll have better luck actually explaining what I mean here.

What I mean is this: If I declare an object in Java, and then initialize it separately, like this:

```
    BufferedImage buffImg;
    buffImg = ImageIO.read("MyImage.jpg");
```

Then Eclipse will turn the object name (buffImg in this case) a special color, add it to the Outline, and generally treat it like an object. It can do the same thing with keywords, strings, comments... you get the idea.

But if I do an "inline declaration", where I declare, instantiate, and initialize the object all on one line, like this:

```
    BufferedImage buffImg = ImageIO.read("MyImage.jpg");
```

Then Eclipse doesn't turn it that special color, doesn't add it to the Outline, and generally treats it like any random, unspecial word, with one exception: code highlighting will still pick out all the instances of that word throughout the code.

My questions, then, are:

1. What do you call this sort of "all-on-one-line" declaration, so that I know what words to put in Google in the future?
2. How do I get Eclipse to recognize it?

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not aware of a special name for what you are describing although it is very common.  I'm not sure why your version of Eclipse is showing different coloring schemes for one use vs. another though.

Comment: This is definitely a declaration. It declares a variable `buffImg`. You don't specify whether it's a local or instance variable declaration, though. Instance variables are always initialized, there is no such thing as a declared, but uninitialized instance var. Coincidentally, Eclipse doesn't give special formatting to local vars, so that may be your case.

Comment: @BlackVegetable: "my version of Eclipse"? Does this mean that your version recognizes the "inline" type just fine? I'm using Indigo - is this a known bug with that version? Maybe this is a good excuse to get Juno...

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: In this case they're all instance vars. However, I tried putting the declarations inside the init() method (which would turn them into local vars), but the formatting behavior didn't change. Eclipse still does/n't recognize them, as described above, whether they are instance or local.

Comment: You may want to have a look at Eclipse's preferences, specifically `Java > Editor > Syntax Coloring`, `General > Editors > Text Editors > Annotations` (set colours for "Occurrences" and "Write Occurrences", and `General > Editors > Text Editors > Quick Diff`. I generally find the overview ruler more helpful than having the outline open all the time, but of course that's rather subjective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.- There is not an special word for single statement declaration and initialization, it is the common way to initialize variables in java.

2.- I think your confusion may come from Fields and local variables.
    Fields are highlighted by Eclipse despite the kind of initialization you use, local variables are not. Also Fields are always displayed in the outline, and local variables are not.

About recognizing local variables in Eclipse you might like to take a look at this answer in SO: [Show All Local Variables in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7579314/show-all-local-variables-in-eclipse), also for more information on local variables and fields you might want to take a look at: [The Java Tutorials: Variables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html).

[image: Fields are on Outline Local Variables are not.]

Regards!

Comment: Aha! I see. Thanks for the answer, and the helpful links!

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing the first example inside a method, it's probably adding buffImg to the Outline as a *warning*. You are leaving it, albeit very briefly, uninitialized. The best practice is your all-in-one declaratation plus initialization across a single line. If you cannot set the local variable immediately, initialize it to null and then reassign it later.

Comment: Specifically, I'm making an applet, so as far as the first example goes, the "uninitialized" (as what it's really doing is initializing it to a default value) declaration is done immediately inside the class (the one after which the file is named). The second line, the separate initialization, is done in the init() method. And I thank you for confirming my initial supposition that the "inline" way is the best practice, as it seems silly to initialize twice, and waste a lot of vertical space doing so, when you can just do it all at once. I just wish I could tell Eclipse that!

Comment: I believe you are saying the two lines in your first example are separated. Line 1 just inside the class block; line 2 inside an init method. In that case, buffImg is a class field declaration. That is perfectly OK to not initialize at that time. It is being color changed and added to the type outline (or whatever it's called) because it is recognized as a field.

In your second example, if you did that entire line inside your init() method, then buffImage is a local reference. No color change for you.

Comment: Sigh. Eclipse is _such_ a color change nazi... at least I can still get soup. Thanks for the info =)

Comment: You can still make it color change. Windows->Preferences->Java->Editor->Syntax Coloring. In the Element textarea/tree, select Java->Local variable declarations. Check Enable. Edit the color and font styles to your heart's content. Ditto for Local variable references if you'd like. They still won't be in the Outline.